# Android OS 4.4.2 fails connecting to MobileFirst server after TLS 1.2 enabled

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst

We have mobile hybrid project running on MobileFirst 7.1.0.00.20170627-0807.

ANDROID VERSIONS 4.4.2 AND EARLIER CANNOT CONNECT TO SERVER USING HTTPS IF ONLY TLS 1.2 IS ENABLED

Getting below clients logs while connecting to worklight server.

```
    07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:146)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at com.worklight.wlclient.certificatepinning.HostNameVerifierWithCertificatePinning.verify(HostNameVerifierWithCertificatePinning.java:42)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at com.worklight.wlclient.TLSSniEnabledSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSSniEnabledSocketFactory.java:94)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:47)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-25 06:13:06.236: W/System.err(4251):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-25 06:13:06.316: D/wl.certManager(4251): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:262 :: Key store cleared.
07-25 06:13:06.636: D/wl.certManager(4251): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:262 :: Key store cleared.
07-25 06:13:06.666: W/PluginManager(4251): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.getClientInstanceIdHeader blocked the main thread for 26ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
```

We are using mobilefirst iFix which already has client SDK with TLS1.2 support.
Do i need to change anything at client/server side?

Comment: 1) Are you using certificate pinning 2) Did you remove the Android environment and re-add it after applying the iFix? 3) Which exact build are you running?

Comment: @VivinK 1) Yes we are using certificate pinning.  2) Yes tried by deleting and adding again android environment but still facing same issue. 3) Running build on android 4.4.2 created through MFP - 7.1.0.00.20170627-0807